# Publish apps on android market

Tags: android

I am an Android applications developer from India. I want to publish my apps on the android market.Is there any restrictions for developers from India to publish apps? Do I need an American bank account for that.
If not can anyone please explain the requirements and procedure for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for publishing free apps, no, there are no restrictions whatsoever.

However, if you plan on publishing paid apps, you should set up a merchant account.

[Click here](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=15867) for more details.

**Edit:** according to [this page](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324), you can't publish paid apps from India, at least for now.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud Hossam for the reply. But can I have free apps with adds on it. So that I can get revenue for it

Comment: @James Yes, you can, you'll need a free AdMob account for that, though.

Comment: Mahmoud Hossam Can I ask you one more question. Can I pay the Developer fee using my Debit card.

Comment: @James I paid for it with my VISA debit card, there are other types of cards supported as well.